# Local variable on the stack loses its value after a function call

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, att, stack-memory

I have a problem trying to print a string and a variable that's pointing to a string. The non-variable string is being printed twice, when in fact, it should print the string `"Test String"` and then the string that's stored in `-4(%ebp)`.

The following code produces the bug, and I see no obvious reason as to why it's happening.

```
.section .text
    .global _start
_start:
    call main
    movl %eax, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
.section .data
LC0:
    .string "world\n"
.section .text
    movl $LC0, -4(%ebp)
.section .data
LC1:
    .string "Test Print\n"
.section .text
    pushl $LC1
    call print
    pushl -4(%ebp)
    call print
    leave
    ret
print:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    pushl 8(%ebp)
    call strlen
    movl %eax, %edx
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
    int $0x80
    leave
    ret
strlen:
    movl $0, %edi
    movl 4(%esp), %ebx
strlen_loop:
    movb (%ebx), %al
    cmpb $0, %al
    je strlen_exit
    incl %edi
    incl %ebx
    jmp strlen_loop
strlen_exit:
    movl %edi, %eax
    ret
```

The code above should produce the following output

```
> Test Print
> world
```

But instead it produces the output

```
> Test Print
> Test Print
```

Though, for some unknown reason, it seems to work as expected when I print `-4(%ebp)` directly after declaring it, like this, but that's not what I want to do every time.

```
    movl $LC0, -4(%ebp)
    pushl -4(%ebp)
    call print
```

Comment: That's because you forgot to allocate the stack. You can't just reference `-4(%ebp)` without allocating.

Comment: That was a silly mistake, thank you.